# Parallels Desktop: Any Chance of Recovering Deleted VM on Mac OS?

Tags: data-recovery, parallels-desktop, file-recovery

I deleted windows 10 VM from my MacBook two days ago. It was pretty large in size, around 50 Gigs, and I deleted to free up some storage. Before deleting, I copied all of my data, and I forgot to copy some important data, which was stored in "Sticky Notes".  :( 
It was in my trash for about 4 days, and I emptied trash two days ago. From last two days, I have been trying different tools, but no luck so far.
I have **tried**:

- RecoverIt
- Aiseesoft Mac Data Recovery
- iSkysoft Data Recovery
- DiskDrill
- Easeus Data Recovery
- Stellar Data Recovery

I tried free / basic / trial versions of those software's. As most of them allows to view files in free version. RecoverIt showed the VM files in first run, but when I purchased the software, it did not show those files. :(

**Q.** Is there any possibility to recover in this case?

**Additional info:**

- VM was stored on second drive of SSD (partition)
- Drive has password encryption enabled
- It's 1.5 TB in size (entire drive scanning is too slow, DiskDrill took around 9 hours to scan the drive)

Comment: Have you been writing to the drive you want to recover from? You say you installed software (Recoverit) which showed the files then didn’t. It may be that installing or writing to that drive wrote over those files.

Comment: Chances are, it’s gone. See: [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/269916/119271) and [this article from Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/help/ssd-drive-data-recovery.html). The more activity you have on the drive drastically reduces the chance of recovering anything

Comment: @SolarMike nope, I did not write any data myself to that drive after that. And as I mentioned, the OS is installed in separate drive so I guess, OS won't be writing much on that drive. However, as I am using machine so there could be some data written by OS etc.

Comment: @Allan thanks for sharing resources, you are right. Because the "RecoverIt" was the very first software, I ran and it showed the file. But I started "Disk Drill" right after that, and it tried to read all block and took a lot of time, and I ran several other software's in parallel to speed up the process. While I was looking for some free options, and I didn't find any working solution so I decided to buy "RecoverIt". Maybe there was a chance, if I buy "RecoverIt".

Comment: Running multiple products simultaneously is not a good idea.  You can end up doing more damage than what you started with.  Same reason you don’t run multiple Anti-Virus.  If you’re not seeing it with the free, you won’t recover it.  The paid version just unlocks the recovery function of the software you have installed.