# Completely delete files from Trash on SSD

Tags: macbook-pro

I've found a file with my personal information in it and I didn't want anyone to see them. So, I trashed the file and permanently deleted it.

Now, I've found out that when you delete a file from the Trash, you only remove a link to it (a pointer).

How do I completely remove it from my hard drive?

- Should I make a very large file full of zeros to overwrite the sectors no longer in use, completely full up my hard drive, then delete it?
- Are there any free, open source tools to recover the file so I know it's gone or not?

I am using MacBook with a SSD drive. If this question is not suitable, please merge it.

Comment: See this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258274/119271

Comment: Thank you so much. It seems to have what I need to know.